# powershell $var has value, but when in if statement - gets false

Tags: powershell

Just making a little menu for zoom usage.
The user insert it's selection, and the script automatically opens zoom to the specific session.
The problem is at  **if (($hashTable.$selection).Count -gt 1)** where $selection does have the value 1 (if I pressed 1) but the expression always gets false - so it proceeds to the else statement.

The goal is to have in the hash table either only a session number or both session number and a password.
After checking if there's more than one value to the key, then I chose my action.

$selection does holds the number the user enters - so why $hashTable.$selection is empty?

```
$hashTable = @{
    1 = '6108514938', 'f'
    2 = 'Val2'
    3 = 'Val3'
}

function Show-Menu
{
    param (
        [string]$Title = 'My Menu'
    )
    Clear-Host
    Write-Host "================ $Title ================"

    Write-Host "1: Press '1' for Algorithms."
    Write-Host "2: Press '2' for this option."
    Write-Host "3: Press '3' for this option."
    Write-Host "Q: Press 'Q' to quit."
}

do
 {
     Show-Menu –Title 'ZOOM Menu'
     $zoomBaseLink = 'zoommtg://zoom.us/join?confno='
     $selectedSession = $null
     
     $selection = Read-Host "Please select session"
     switch ($selection)
     {
         '1' { $selectedSession = ($hashTable.1) } 
         '2' { $selectedSession = ($hashTable.2) }
         '3' { 'You chose option #3' }
     }

     if($selection -ne 'q') {
         if (([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($selectedSession)))  { 
            Write-Host 'session is null or empty' 
         }
         else {
         Write-Host $selection
         Write-Host $selectedSession

         pause
         <#($hashTable.$selection) always gets false.#>
         if (($hashTable.$selection).Count -gt 1) { Write-Host 'here 1'; Write-Host $hashTable.$selection[1] }
         else{ Write-Host 'here 2'; Write-Host ($zoomBaseLink + $selectedSession) }
         }
         $selectedSession = $null
         }
         pause
 }
 until ($selection -eq 'q')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem ist, that you didn't convert the variable `$selection` to an integer.

```
[int]$selection = [convert]::ToInt32($selection, 10)
```

If you do that first, it will work (tested):

```
if($selection -ne 'q') {
     if (([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($selectedSession)))  { 
        Write-Host 'session is null or empty' 
     }
     else {
           Write-Host $selection
           Write-Host $selectedSession

           pause
           [int]$selection = [convert]::ToInt32($selection, 10)
           <#($hashTable.$selection) always gets false.#>
           if (($hashTable.$selection).Count -gt 1) { Write-Host 'here 1'; Write-Host $hashTable.$selection[1] }
           else{ Write-Host 'here 2'; Write-Host ($zoomBaseLink + $selectedSession) }
     }
$selectedSession = $null
[string]$selection = $null
}
pause
```

Please let me know if it worked and if it did, please mark my post as the answer :)

Comment: well... it did word, but it caused another problem.
now whe I wanna quit (using 'q') I, as expected, get an error:
"Cannot convert value "q" to type "System.Int32". Error: "Input string was not in a correct format."

Comment: @JamesBlue Change your `q` to `4` for quit would seem like the easiest solution.

Comment: @JamesBlue you can just change the variable back to a string again with "[string]$selection = $null" at the end of the if statement (I edited the answer)